# Groovy Script to insert database entries with unique key

Tags: database, groovy

I am writing a groovy script to read data from an CSV file and then pull inserts into database. I have gotten everything to work EXCEPT for generating a unique primary key or autoincrement for each insert. The unique key is campusID.  Here is the script.

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
        "xxxx", "xxxx", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
      def campus = sql.dataSet("CAMPUS")



new File("C:\\test.csv").splitEachLine(",") {fields ->
        campus.add(
          campusId: // Need to generate a unique key here

          campusShortName: fields[1],
          campusUrl: fields[2])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique key is usually handled by the database, not by the code.

Some databases (like MySQL) accept setting the autogenerated field to `null`, others require that the column isn't provided at all.  So, either remove the `campusId` from your query, or set it to `null`, and make sure the column is set to be an [`AUTO_INCREMENT` column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

If you need the ID that was inserted (for example, to use as a foreign key), you may be better off using the normal SQL methods, and check the [return value of the `executeInsert` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#executeInsert%28groovy.lang.GString%29)

Comment: Setting the autoincrement in MySQL did it! Thanks a lot.